Automated measuring system for measuring the focal length of lenses
I am working on a project to build a system to measure the focal length of lenses. My aim to measure the focal lengths between 25 mm to 200 mm, And i was thinking of using the  maginification method . I came across this research paper "A Technique to Measure Focal Length of a Lens with no Bulk Motion using Tunable Optics and Optical MEMS Technology" where they used tuneable lenses to minimize mechanical motion, I was wondering if it's possible to adapt this method to my aim or if there are other novel ways to do this?

For clarity, you might give a reference to that research paper you mention.

If the idea works in the visible, it should work in the UV. But can you find a variable focus lens that word from $25$ - $200$ nm? Is there a reason that it is easier to change the focal length of a lens rather than adjust the distances between elements in your system?

A tunable lens has a limited range of focal lengths it can operate over. You have to check if it would cover the range you need. In general, if you are trying to measure things accurately, a tunable lens is not great. Temperature affects or change to the liquid material that is doing the tuning would affect the accuracy of the measurement.

Your idea has already been widely commercialized, as follows:
Optometrists have machines which automatically determine the magnification power of the lens in your eye and furnish the correction factor necessary to restore your vision to normal. You look into the eyepiece of the machine, which projects a scene of a barn atop a grassy hillside. You look at the barn and the machine then receives the image reflected off of your retina (which has by then passed through your lens twice) and adds or subtracts the diopters needed for a correct focus.

These instruments have a limited range (because the focus error of your eye might be limited).  They are also only typically accurate to an eighth of a diopter, because if someone's eye glass prescription varies by an eighth of a diopter they are unlikely to notice.
